# Route 53 two hosted zones with the same domain overriding

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-route53

So I have a Hosted Zone(**H1**) for my Custom Domain Name for API-Gateway created via Cloudformation CDK initially.
Then I created a hosted zone(**H2**) for an ALB with the exact same domain name.

After creating the new hosted zone (**H2**), It seemed to overwrite the previous one (all traffic to the domain was going to the ALB) even though the previous Hosted Zone (**H1**) and its records still existed in Route 53 (untouched). Is this the expected behavior?

I ended up deleting (**H2**) but it did not renable the old hosted zone, now the domain is sort of just dead even though the hosted zone is still showing on Route53.

Comment: Sounds like something you should raise with [AWS Support](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/).

Answer (score 0):

Yea I found the issue. My hosted zones were actually created for a subdomain in which a parent hosted zone delegated sub domain to my hosted zone via NS record.